# Django unit test suite "--functions=" couldn't be empty

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unit-testing

I'm upgrading a Django app from version `1.10.7` to `1.11.2`.
After the upgrade, **runserver** command works well, but when I try to run the **unit test suite** the following error raised:

```
CommandError: Option `--functions=...` couldn't be empty
```

To run the unit test suite, I'm using the following command:

```
python src\main\manage.py test --noinput
```

As you can see, I'm not using any `--function` parameter and this is the same command that I used before the upgrade. 
I reach the same situation if I run the test suite specifying the file to run. 
 
I have also tried to run the help function for the manage command and no `--functions` parameter is showed. 
I'm a little bit confused on this issue, and I don't find any information about this error in both, documentation and release notes.

Anyone knows how this error is raised and how to fix it?

I'm running Django 1.11.2 and Python 2.7

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `--functions` argument you see almost certainly doesn't come from Django. `CommandError` (probably) comes from `django.core.management.base`. Do you have any [custom management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/)?

Comment: Yes, you are right, both parameter and error message come from a custom command. But why this happen? i mean, only in django 1.11.2? I'm try to run the complete test suite...

Comment: It might not have been caused by the upgrade. Are you entirely sure that this worked with Django 1.10? In any case, we'll need to see the custom command and whatever test(s) call it to help further.

Comment: Yes i'm sure. The custom command that raise this error is called "check", so probably the choice of the name is not a good one because I saw that there is a django-admin check command

Comment: Ah, that could be the problem. But `django-admin check` was added in Django 1.10; I'm not sure why it would become an issue when you upgrade from 1.10.7 to 1.11. In any case, try renaming your management command and see if your tests run successfully.

Comment: Yes, renaming custom command works well! thank you very much!

Comment: Great. I'll add a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/) called `check` that conflicts with [one of Django's built-in commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#check). For whatever reason, `manage.py test` is calling your custom command instead of the built-in one.

Renaming your custom command to something that doesn't conflict should solve the problem.